# Integer arrays comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question of JS arrays.

Example:

```
var fullArr = [1,2,3,4];
var partArr = [2,3];
var newArr = [];
```

We have a main array `fullArr` and a partial array `partarr`. I want to create a function/filter, which is looking for existing items in `fullArr` and not in `partArr`.
In this example above `newArr` must be equal to [1,4].

I've tried doing something like this, but it's not working properly.

```
for (var k in fullArray) {   // [1,2,3,4]
  for (var j in selectedArray) {  // [1,4]
    if (fullArray[k] == selectedArray[j]) {
      newArray.splice(selectedArray[j] - 1, 1); // must be [2,3]
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```

What is a good way of making this? Thanks.

Comment: `but it's not working properly` how's it not working? What result does it give you?

Comment: A side note, it probably doesn't matter with your code in particular, but in general, it's a bad idea to use `for...in` with an array because the order isn't guaranteed. Use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Using `Array.filter` is the easier solution, but you might also want to look at the documentation for [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) because you aren't using it right. But since you are (presumably) trying to add an item to `newArr`, it would be easier to do with `push`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one

```
var newArr = fullArr.filter(function(f) { // The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
    return partArr.indexOf(f) == -1; // The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
})
```

to impress the girls, you can also

```
var newArr = fullArr.filter(function(f) {
    return !~partArr.indexOf(f);
})
```

Comment: A little explanation would probably improve your answer

Comment: really? Array.filter and Array.indexOf should be the bread and butter of newbie javascript programmers

Comment: Well clearly they aren't to the OP. So maybe you can help them out a little? Or else, why did you bother answering?

Comment: @MattBurland you know, I've answered many questions where the OP responds "oh, of course, I should've seen that" ... can't win :p - explanations added, totally plagiarised from mdn :p

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for your requirement.

```
var fullArr = [1,2,3,4];
var partArr = [2,3];
var newArr = [];

for(var i=0;i<fullArr.length;i++){
   if(partArr.indexOf(fullArr[i]) == -1)
      newArr.push(fullArr[i]);
};
```

Here is the working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/w5918rxh/1/)

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you want a common part between arrays. Obviously you can choose `splice` or `indexOf` to have `O(n * m)` or even `O(m * n^2)` performance. It's obviously suboptimal for any array larger than few elements

Or you can use objects as hash maps to find differences in (in worst case) `O(n + m log m)`:

```
var fullArr = [1,2,3,4];
var partArr = [2,3];
var temporaryObject = Object.create(null);
partArr.forEach(el=>temporaryObject[el] = true); // temporaryObject after this operation is {"2": true, "3": true}
var newArr = fullArr.filter(el=>temporaryObject[el]);
```

In this example I have used ES6 feature called "[arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)". It translates to following ES5 code:

```
var partArr = [2, 3];
var temporaryObject = Object.create(null);
partArr.forEach(function (el) {
    temporaryObject[el] = true;
}); // temporaryObject after this operation is {"2": true, "3": true}
var newArr = fullArr.filter(function (el) {
    return temporaryObject[el];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter()` function that works on arrays:

```
var newArr = fullArr.filter(function(val, i, arr) {
  return partArr.indexOf(val) === -1;
});
```

This will return a new array containing the values of every iteration that returns `true`.

Should you ever need to do this on an object in the future a great way is to first convert the object keys to an array and then run the filter:

```
Object.keys(myObj).function(val, i, arr) {
  return partArr.indexOf(val) === -1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Here are few other approaches:

```
var fullArr = [1,2,3,4];
var partArr = [2,3];
var newArr = [];

1. 
fullArr.map(function(element){
  if(partArr.indexOf(element) === -1) newArr.push(element);
})
console.log(newArr);

2. 
for(i in fullArr){
   if(partArr.indexOf(fullArr[i]) === -1) newArr.push(fullArr[i]);
}
console.log(newArr);

3.
fullArr.forEach(function(element){
    if(partArr.indexOf(element) === -1) newArr.push(element);
})

console.log(newArr);
```